# Probability and stopping time

Tags: probability

We have 3 groups of people $A,B,C$. People from each group are comming to the party individualy. Party stops where there is one person from each group (stopping time). Probabilities, that person from each group comes to the party are $p_1,p_2,p_3$ and arrivals are independent. I don't know if this formula is correct and if there is any other easyer way to calculate all the posibilities when process stops.

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} {{n+i}\choose{i}}p_1^i p_2^n p_3
+ \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} {{k+j}\choose{j}}p_1^k p_3^j p_2+
 \sum_{l=1}^{\infty} \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} {{l+m}\choose{m}}p_2^l p_3^m p_1
$$

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what you are trying to compute. If both sums to go $\infty$, the result is $1$ (you cover all the cases). If you are trying to calculate the probability that the party will have $n$ people where the last one is type $p_1$ then the probability is:

$$ (1-p_1)^{n-1} p_1 \left(1-(\tfrac{p_2}{p_2+p_3})^{n-1} - (\tfrac{p_3}{p_2+p_3})^{n-1} \right) $$

where $(1-p_1)^{n-1} p_1$ is the probability that the first person of type $p_1$ came at time $n$ and the $(\ldots)$ represents the conditional probability that given only type $p_2,p_3$ people, they are not all of the same type. Since $p_1+p_2+p_3=1$, this can be slightly simplified:

$$ p_1 \left((1-p_1)^{n-1}-{p_2}^{n-1} - {p_3}^{n-1} \right) $$

Thus, the probability that the party has exactly $n$ people can be computed by adding three similar terms (one where the last one is $p_2$ and one where the last one is $p_3$).

Comment: For example if we have Homogenous Poisson Process, so they are comming with intensity HPP($p_1$), HPP($p_2$) and HPP($p_3$) and I would like to calculate the time when the process stops. I need to use Wald's identity: $E(\sum_{i=1}^K T_i )= E(K)E(T_i)$ where $E(T_i)=1/(p_1+p_2+p_3)$ and K={inf i, in X_1,X_2 ...X_n there is one with probabiliy p_1, one with probability p_2 and one with probability p_3}. So the E(K) is the probability you just calculated with all 3 options?

Comment: Yes. I think that in this case, you can calculate the expected time directly, it's only few summations that look like the expectation of a geometric random variable.

Answer (score 1):

Each of your three infinite sums is the probability that the last person to arrive belongs to group $\ C\ $, $ B\ $, $\ A\ $, respectively.  If $\ T\ $ is the number of the last arrival, then
\begin{align}
P(T=t)&=\sum_{i=0}^{t-1}{t-1\choose i}p_1^ip_2^{t-i-1}p_3+ \sum_{i=0}^{t-1}{t-1\choose i}p_1^ip_3^{t-i-1}p_2+\sum_{i=0}^{t-1}{t-1\choose i}p_2^ip_3^{t-i-1}p_1\\
&=\left(p_1+p_2\right)^{t-1}p_3+ \left(p_1+p_3\right)^{t-1}p_2+ \left(p_2+p_3\right)^{t-1}p_1\\
&=\left(1-p_3\right)^{t-1}p_3+ \left(1-p_2\right)^{t-1}p_2+ \left(1-p_1\right)^{t-1}p_1\ ,
\end{align}
and its mean value is
\begin{align}
\sum_{t=1}^\infty t \left(\left(1-p_3\right)^{t-1}p_3+ \left(1-p_2\right)^{t-1}p_2+ \left(1-p_1\right)^{t-1}p_1\right)&=\frac{1}{p_3}+\frac{1}{p_2}+\frac{1}{p_1}\ .
\end{align}